# Does disabling of authorization implicit flow still adhere to OIDC standard?

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid-connect

According to https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/implicit/, using the implicit flow is no longer recommended for nowadays apps. Thus, I intend to disable it.

According to https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Authentication, this means that I won't support `id_token` and `id_token token` response types.

However, for the discovery endpoint, according to https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-discovery-1_0.html#ProviderMetadata,

> **response_types_supported**: **REQUIRED**. JSON array containing a list of the OAuth 2.0 response_type values that this OP supports. **Dynamic OpenID Providers MUST support the code, id_token, and the id_token token Response Type values**.

Now I'm confused. What is a *Dynamic OpenID Provider*? Is it wrong to not advertise `id_token` and `id_token token` on the discovery endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BASICS**

Including flows like `code id_token` in the OpenID metadata does no harm. It is what your clients use that counts.

If you prefer though, disable both `token` and `id_token`. You will then be aligned with the [latest FAPI 2.0 security recommendations](https://openid.net/specs/fapi-2_0-security-profile-ID2.html#name-main-differences-to-fapi-10), which recommend using only `response_type=code`.

This avoids ever receiving tokens on the front channel. If these tokens are JWTs, as for ID tokens, they could result in disclosure of personal data in the browser history or server logs, since JWTs are easily readable.

**ADVANCED**

A Dynamic OpenID Provider implements some extra features from [Section 15.2 of the OIDC spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#DynamicMTI). This is used in dynamic business scenarios.

An example might be a bank providing Open Banking capabilities, where a merchant could get connected using dynamic client registration and a client certificate issued by a banking authority.

Dynamic OpenID providers may sometimes need to support using `response_type=code id_token`. This was one of the [FAPI 1.0](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-2-1_0.html#id-token-as-detached-signature-1) options, though it also required encrypted ID tokens to protect against the type of information disclosure I mention above.